# Is there a way I can write $('.select2').select2({ width: "100%", placeholder: "Select Here" }) as a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have uncaught type error in my console saying that the following segment is not a function. How am I supposed to write it so that it can be as a function?

```
$(function() {
    $('.select2').select2({
        width: "100%",
        placeholder: "Select Here"
    })
```

I have tried asking my friends what might be the error but they find it hard to help

Comment: It's likely you have not included the Select2 script in the HTML before calling this code. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We'd really like a [mre] to guide us in answering (and you in asking).

Comment: Please include enough code to reproduce the issue.  As it is, your code, as provided, is missing `});` so it's hard to tell if that's the problem or some other issue.  See [mcve].

Comment: Please also provide the exact message, looks like in this case that would be: `TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function`.  In which case, see comment above as select2 is loaded at the time your code runs. If you think you have loaded select2, then it's likely there's *another* jquery load that is removing it.

Comment: I agree with Heretic Monkey. Your script is likely executing before the Select2 script has loaded and been parsed. Select2 itself depends on jQuery, so that must also be loaded before your code can execute.